# Can I use IPN with PayPal Advanced?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've searched here on numerous queries but have not found a completely clear answer.  Simply put, if I purchase PayPal Advanced (currently using standard PayPal), can I use their IPN?  Or do I need to upgrade to Premier or Business?

Costs prohibit using these, but the $5.00 a month for Advanced is do-able.

tia
_mark

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Instant Payment Notifications are specific to PayPal Standard, Express Checkout and PayPal Payments Pro. PayPal Payments Advanced is using the Payflow Gateway so it will not work with the PayPal Instant Payment Notifications properly. To solve this issue the Payflow Gateway and PayPal Payments Advanced uses a feature called Silent Post. 
Here is the information from the PayPal Developer site:
[Silent Post Information from PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#silent-posts)
Info from the Developer Site:

> The Silent Post feature returns either a short list of data or all of the data that was submitted for the transaction. You can control what is returned to you via the optional ECHODATA parameter: